# mysqli prepared statement inside a function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

So I am trying to run a prepared statement inside a function, but keep seeming to have difficulty passing in the mysqli connection statement. I have definitely exceeded 100 combinations of tries by now...

I use the connection for another prepared statement prior to using it in the function. I have even declared my connection variables within the statement due to the difficulties in passing in a in include() to the function

```
include('phpsqlinfo_dbinfo.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $database);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, email, username, password, gender, homelat")

//blah blah blah run a statement here. I omitted this statement for brevity purposes.

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();


function storeTokenForUser($username,$token) {
    echo "running2";

    echo $token;
    echo $username;
    $host="";
    $dbusername="XXXX";
    $dbpassword="XXXX";
    $database="XXXX";

    global $mysqli;

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO cookielogin (username, token) VALUES (?,?)"); 
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $token1);
    $stmt->execute();
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo("error".htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error).htmlspecialchars($stmt1->error));
    }
    echo"running3";
}


function cookie($username,$mysqli) {
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
storeTokenForUser($username, $token);
$cookie = $username . ':' . $token;
$mac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cookie, 9842);
$cookie .= ':' . $mac;
setcookie('rememberme', $cookie);
        echo"running1";
}
```

I have gotten different errors throughout my efforts, but right now, this give me:

```
Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/loginphp.php on line 63

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/loginphp.php on line 64
```

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at the colour codeing

Comment: Your snippet opens and promply closes a `mysqli` connection, and then you have a function that isn't called. If you're going to post a question, post code that makes some sense.

Comment: sorry, it was called from in another function. added now

Comment: and sorry I deleted that prepared statement and a lot of other junk because they were irrelevant/ would have made it harder to interpret.

Comment: The statement that you removed for brevity is relevant because you call `$mysqli->close()` right after it.

Comment: Just remove both `$stmt->close()` and `$mysqli->close()`.  PHP will close them implicitly when they are no longer needed.  The statement would only need to be closed manually if you did not fetch all rows from it before attempting a different statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

To fix the error and:

```
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $token1);
```

`$token1` is undefined.

Comment: Yes I realize I shouldn't have posted that. That was one of my last attempts after trying without it most the time. removing it has not worked so far, and did not previously.

Comment: @ambe5960 Alright show me what the next problem is (update your post).

Comment: not getting any error after removing the stmt->close() and mysqli->close() but still not inserting.

Comment: @ambe5960 Are you sure you're calling the function (i.e. calling `cookie`)? It seems perfectly fine to me.

Comment: yeah I'm getting the "running" echoes.  When I put the question marks in quotes, it inserts two question marks. Which suggests to me I am binding them wrong somehow.

Comment: @ambe5960 It's two question marks because that's how prepared statements escape them. By the way, what's with the `$host`, `$dbusername`, etc. in the function?

Comment: those are just the connection information, which is working well.

Comment: @ambe5960 Why are they in the method though? `$mysqli` was already instantiated beforehand. Is the first prepared statement working?

Comment: because they are brought in from an 'include('sqldataseinfo') file, which didn't seem to be passing to the function. yes, first prepared statement is good.

Comment: hey don't waste too much brain power on it. I bet it's something silly. Ill let you know if I get it.

Comment: @ambe5960 I think I found it. `$token1` is undefined in the binding statement.

Comment: @ambe5960 It's always the stupidest things. Anyway, +1 on the question. Happy programming~

Comment: Appreciate it. To you as well. +1 on all your comments :P